# Найти массив дат

Tags: дата, php

Пусть `$wk=48`, `$year=2011`, где `$wk` номер недели в году. Тогда

```
$days=array("2011-11-28","2011-11-29","2011-11-30","2011-12-01",
"2011-12-02","2011-12-03","2011-12-04");
```

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ найти этот массив (7 дней, с `Пн` по `Вс`), если даны только `$wk` и `$year`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Какие то сложные у вас решения :)

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+48 weeks", strtotime("2011-01-01 00:00:00")));
```

ну и цикл для получения недели.

**Ок, для понедельника:**

```
$t = strtotime("+48 weeks", strtotime("2011-01-01 00:00:00"));

$monday = strtotime('this monday', $t);
if ($monday > $t) {
    $monday = strtotime('last monday', $t);
}

echo date('D Y-m-d', $monday)."\n";
```

Ваши аргументы ? :)

Comment: И еще надо найти понедельник - не факт, что +48 weeks попадет на него. =)

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: >Ваши аргументы ? :)

**Слишком** просто. =)

Answer (score 4):

```
$wk = 48;
$year = 2011;

$date = new DateTime($year . '-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P' . $wk . 'W'));
$day = $wk*7 - $date->format('w') + 1;

$date = new DateTime($year . '-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P' . $day . 'D'));
for($i = 0; $i < 7; ++$i){
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d'), '<br>';
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}
```

Но только объект DateTime появился с php 5.3.0.

Answer (score 2):

```
$weekNumber = 48;
$year = 2011;
//86400
$beginYear = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $year);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 365; $i++)
{
    $days[] = date('Y-m-d', $beginYear);
    $beginYear += 86400;
}

$beginWeek = (($weekNumber - 1) * 7 + 2);
for ($i = $beginWeek; $i < $beginWeek + 7; $i++)
{
    echo $days[$i] . '<br>';
}
```

PS. високосный год не учитывается.